# MVC Kendo Diagram Set Connectors Data Source

Tags: kendo-ui, connection, datasource, diagram

I'm trying to set connectors datasource in my diagram, but the connectors are not set.

When I inspect the diagram, members source is filled but connectors source is empty.

My code is something like this:

```
Html.Kendo().Diagram()
//Set Members DataSource
.DataSource(ds => ds
.Read(read => read.Action("MembersActionName", "ControllerName")
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id("MemberId");
    })
)
//Set Connectors DataSource
.ConnectionsDataSource(cds => cds
    .Read(read => read.Action("ConnectorsActionName", "ControllerName")
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.From("SourceMemberId");
        m.To("DestinationMemberId");
        m.Id("ConnectionId");
    })
)
.AutoBind(true)
.Layout(l => l
    .Type(DiagramLayoutType.Tree)
    .Subtype(DiagramLayoutSubtype.Down)
)
.ShapeDefaults(sd => sd.Visual("visualTemplate"))
.ConnectionDefaults(cd =>
{
    cd.Stroke(s => s.Color("#006bab").Width(1));
    cd.Type(DiagramConnectionType.Polyline);
    cd.StartCap(st =>
    {
        st.Type("FilledCircle");
        st.Fill(stf => stf.Color("#006bab"));
    });
    cd.EndCap(st =>
    {
        st.Type("ArrowEnd");
        st.Fill(stf => stf.Color("#006bab"));
    });
})
.Render();
```